# why the absolute position does not work in ie 6 and 7

Tags: html, css

Pretty simple html codes:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: 400px; background-color: red">
    <div style="position: absolute; top:2px;bottom:2px;left:2px;right:2px; background-color: gray">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

While I want the inner div will hold all the place inside the outer div with (2px margin).

It works in ff/chrome/ie8 Howver it does not work in ie 6 and 7.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A suggestion:

If you just need the margin, you can use this code, just with the inner `DIV` alone:

```
<div style="background-color: gray; width: 296px; height: 396px; border: 2px solid red;">
    content
</div>
```

If not just for the border, please see the solution to the **IE Fix** below.

#### Pretty simple answer:

You need to set the `width` and `height`!

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: 400px; background-color: red">
    <div style="position: absolute; top:2px;bottom:2px;left:2px;right:2px; background-color: gray; width: 296px; height: 396px;">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/okibat/1

Comment: indeed, absolute positioned elements need a dimension, set by width & height.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `IE 6, 7` you cannot put the opposite direction in the same declaration.

For example

```
.absolute {
    top: 0;
    /* you can't put bottom: 0; here in IE since it the opposite */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE6 needs the div to be nested into another div. Only then can you absolute position the inner div… sometimes! If I moved my div to some parts of the xhtml it worked as intended, but in certain places it was inheriting something from a div around it (NOT inside it). I couldn’t find any reasonable explanation for why it worked in some areas and not others, but I did realize that whatever it was, the outer div absorbed it and allowed the inner div to be positioned correctly.

Create one Css class like

```
.bor{ 
border:solid 1px #ccc;
padding:10px; margin:10px;
}
```

Then add this css to   content

```
div id="wrapper" class="bor">

 <div id="header" class="bor">
    <div id="logo">Logo goes here</div>
    <div id="phone">9876543210</div>
 </div><!-- #header -->

 <div id="mainContent" class="bor">

    <div id="sidebar" class="bor">
```